# Using Sprintf() to left pad a string?

Tags: string

I've been at this all day, and I just can't seem to wrap my mind around how to use sprintf() to set a width for my string so that my characters are right justified.

What I'm trying to do is scooch my output over to the right on my touchscreen when the value is positive.
My output string is always a predictable length, so it seems like it should be easy.
I tried concatenating a string with just a space in it, and every other way I could think of to add a space to the beginning of my string. No luck.

```
char stringval[8] = 1.08;
char juststringval[8];
            if (hashpos > 0 && hashpos < 10) { 

                sprintf(juststringval,  " %5s" , stringval);
                Serial.println(juststringval);
            }
```

output:

```
1.08 (no spaces in front)
```

In case you're curious why I need to use a string, my touchscreen will print floats, but my library won't rotate them properly.
Only strings can be rotated the way I need them.

Isn't there some simple way of doing this?

**EDIT:**

It seems I can use the width trick as long as I include some character besides an empty space.
For example:

```
void setup()
{
char stringval[33] = "1.08";
char juststringval[33];
char space[] = "rr";         ////THIS WORKS: OUTPUT IS  rr      1.08
float hashpos = 1.08;
if (hashpos > 0 && hashpos < 10) {

    sprintf(juststringval, "%s  %7s", space, stringval);
    Serial.println(juststringval);
}
}

void setup()
{
char stringval[33] = "1.08";
char juststringval[33];
char space[] = " ";     ////THIS DOESNT WORK. OUTPUT IS 1.08 LEFT JUSTIFIED
float hashpos = 1.08;
if (hashpos > 0 && hashpos < 10) {

    sprintf(juststringval, "%s  %7s", space, stringval);
    Serial.println(juststringval);
}
}
```

But I can't live with other characters in my string.
Isn't there something I can do?

Comment: Right justification is the default. Have you tried printing another string above or below it to compare?

Comment: Yes, and the default is left justification. When you print something on a new line, it starts on the left, just like words on a page.

Comment: Does it work if you supply a left-padded string?

Comment: No, it's always as far over to the left as possible. Both in my serial port and on my touchscreen.

Even if I artificially insert spaces into "stringval"

Comment: Printing in general starts at the left, but within the field described by the format spec - `%5s` in your case, the string will be right justified within that 5-char field (assuming the string is 5 characters or less). How wide is your screen? If you're trying to right-justify to the width of a 20-char screen, f/ex, you'll need a (20+1) char buffer, and execute:`sprintf(buffer, "%20s", stringval); Serial.print(buffer);` This will print a line of 20 characters, space padded on the left, ending in your "stringval".

Comment: My text begins at a certain pixel coordinate on the screen. Whenever my output lacks a minus sign, I need an extra space. But what I'm saying is that this method does not work. In both my serial port and on my touchscreen, the output is always as far left as possible.

And unfortunately I cant get away with changing the starting coordinate.

Comment: xxprintf() functions don't know about algebraic signs (or any other numeric feature) within strings. For that, you'll have to make a conversion to string from some numeric format that observes the (minus or space) convention for printing signs. As to right justification, I just ran your code, tweaking the field width, and printing to the Arduino IDE terminal window. The output did indeed move farther to the right with larger field widths...

Comment: ... However, I first tested it in Eclipse, whose terminal uses a variable width font, and the spaces were tiny enough not to make much difference. With the Arduino IDE's terminal and a fixed-width font, it was much more obvious.

Comment: @JRobert- I'm currently using Visual Micro for Visual Studio. And my problem isn't with detecting the minus sign. That's unrelated. But I wonder if it's just a quirk of my serial monitor.

Comment: It WAS a quirk of my serial monitor.

Comment: I just tried and to my surprise a format string of "% 5s" actually prints leading spaces if the string is shorter than 5 characters.

Answer (score 2):

The mistake in question and in comments (except of Bigoldsofty's comment), is missing character for justifying. This character should be in format string before the required width. `"% 5s"` not `"%5s"`